# How do I find how much space TFS is using

Tags: tfs-sdk

I'm tring to find out how much space TFS is using.  Is there a simple check free space command on TFS?

Also is there a way to poll TFS for the amount of hard drive space left and see when large changes or large amount of files have been added and by whom for a given week or day?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "how much space TFS is using"? Using on the server? Which server? TFS stores your source in one SQL Server database, and also has a data warehouse and Analysis Services cube, and maybe uses Reporting Services and SharePoint.

Comment: yeah - first thing is check your available space on the data partition used for your dedicated or standalone SQL box. then add some counters to perfmon to keep an eye on it if your close to some threshold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm tring to find out how much space
>   TFS is using. Is there a simple check
>   free space command on TFS?

Projects are not partitioned in the database in such a way that you can easily figure this out. Of course if you just want to see how much space all collections are using you can take a look at your db size.

Here is a good [article to read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/02/22/tfs-size-estimation.aspx) that gives you a rough estimate of space used for files, work items etcetera.

> Also is there a way to poll TFS for
>   the amount of hard drive space left
>   and see when large changes or large
>   amount of files have been added and by
>   whom for a given week or day?

TFS doesn't control the amount of HDD space you have left on your drive.  You can however in code check this by doing something like:

using [System.IO.DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)

```
var drive = new DriveInfo("DRIVE_LETTER");
long freeSpace= drive.freeSpace;
```

As for your final question (see when large changes or large amounts of files have been added and by whom), [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsreporting/thread/d02c6fd3-a762-4830-8ec2-63671ed7c9ae) demonstrates how to do what you are describing using TFS API.

Comment: like the link on doing the bit through API. + 1 for that. Good work!